# Regular expression as optional with maximum limit of 1

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex. Facing some issues while making one expression as optional and if it exists then it should not be repeated. In the below case I want `%23` to be optional and if it occurs then it should not be repeated. But in below case it's working for optional but not for repeat case.

It's giving me `true` even if I put string as:

```
-113%23%2313113098A%2F--
```

Could someone suggest how to make it optional and not repetitive.  This is my regex:

```
(%23)?([0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|-).*$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to avoid matching repeating instances of `%23`:

```
^(?:[0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|[-%])(?!(?:.*?%23){2}).*$
```

**Breakup:**

```
(?!             # start negative lookahead
(?:.*?%23){2}   # match 0 or more chars followed by %23, {2} matches 2 repeats
)               # end lookahead
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cY5qA3/1)

However if requirement is to avoid **consecutive repeats** then use:

```
^(?!.*?(?:%23){2})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have modify it to "^(?!(?:.*?%23){2})([0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|-).*$" but its working for other expression but not for "%23ABC". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Saurabh you can use: `^(?:[0-9]|[A-Z]|%2F|[-%])(?!(?:.*?%23){2}).*$` for your regex